# Jekyll theme doesn't work on Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I tried to create a github page with Jekyll. The jekyll theme appears when I work with the local host, but when I run the code through the github page the theme is not visible and the pages are not working on my github page.

[image: My website in github]

I tried to apply files in here https://github.com/bogoli/-folio.

My page is in here https://github.com/Hazan-su/folio

I'm new to jekyll so I'm not sure exactly where I went wrong, can you please tell me my mistake?

Comment: https://github.com/hazan-su/folio returns a 404. Have you made it a private repository? According to [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site) you'll need to set the visibility to public.

Answer (score 0):

Use the About tab in the page of the github repo to see the stdout from the jekyll build workflow. More than likely there will be an informative error message there.